# How to get one table field values from another table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table cranedetails(fields are : `cf_did , cf_firstname, cf_cranetype` )

```
cf_did   cf_firstname     cf_cranetype 
1        Alexy            2,3    
2        Thomas           11,6,3  
3        Thomas           5,6,11,3        
4        Thomasxc         1,6,9,4         
5        Thomaseg         11,12,3
```

I have another table  cranetype (`cf_did,cf_cname`)

```
cf_ctid     cf_ctname
   1       MOBILE CRANES
   2       ROUGH TERRAIN CRANES
   3       ALL TERRAIN CRANES
   4       CRAWLER CRANES
   5       YARD CRANES
   6       ARICULATING BOOM CRANES
   7       TRUCK CRANES: ARTICULATING BOOM
   8       TRUCK CRANES: LATTICE BOOM
   9       TRUCK CRANES: TELESCOPIC BOOM
   10      TRUCK LOADER CRANES
   11      ELEVATORS
   12      ELEVATOR – HYDRAULIC
```

I want to display values like this,
eg:

```
id:    name:        cranetype

1      Alexy       ROUGH TERRAIN CRANES,ALL TERRAIN CRANES
2      Thomas      ELEVATORS,ARICULATING BOOM CRANES,ALL TERRAIN CRANES
```

and so on.

How to get table cranedetails field `cf_cranetype` values (`2,3`) name from table  `cranetype` `cf_ctnamefield` (ROUGH TERRAIN CRANES,ALL TERRAIN CRANES).

I am sect $did=1. and use this code

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cf_directory` WHERE `cf_did` = '$did'",$con);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);$cn= $row['11']; 
$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `cf_cranetype`  WHERE `cf_ctid`= '$cn'",$con);
<?php  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
     $cranename=$row2['cf_ctname']; ?>
<?php echo $cranename;?>
```

but the output is:

```
id:    name:        cranetype

1      Alexy       ROUGH TERRAIN CRANES
```

I want:

```
id:    name:        cranetype

1      Alexy       ROUGH TERRAIN CRANES,ALL TERRAIN CRANES
```

Comment: You should really reformat the question and the code examples to make it more readable.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `FIND_IN_SET()` can do the trick, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simply `GROUP_CONCAT()` together with `FIND_IN_SET()` for that:

```
SELECT
    cd.cf_did AS id,
    cd.cf_firstname AS name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ct.cf_ctname SEPARATOR ', ') AS cranetype
FROM
    cranedetails cd,
    cranetype ct
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(ct.cf_ctid, cd.cf_cranetype)
GROUP BY
    cd.cf_did,
    cd.cf_firstname
```

Output is:

```
+----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | name     | cranetype                                                                             |
+----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Alexy    | ROUGH TERRAIN CRANES, ALL TERRAIN CRANES                                              |
|  2 | Thomas   | ARICULATING BOOM CRANES, ELEVATORS, ALL TERRAIN CRANES                                |
|  3 | Thomas   | ALL TERRAIN CRANES, YARD CRANES, ARICULATING BOOM CRANES, ELEVATORS                   |
|  4 | Thomasxc | CRAWLER CRANES, ARICULATING BOOM CRANES, TRUCK CRANES: TELESCOPIC BOOM, MOBILE CRANES |
|  5 | Thomaseg | ALL TERRAIN CRANES, ELEVATORS, ELEVATOR – HYDRAULIC                                   |
+----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set
```

If you want to group the result only by name (because there are duplicated names), just remove `cd.cf_did` from the query and add `DISTINCT` to filter duplicated `cranetype` values, i.e:

```
SELECT
    cd.cf_firstname AS name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ct.cf_ctname SEPARATOR ', ') AS cranetype
FROM
    cranedetails cd,
    cranetype ct
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(ct.cf_ctid, cd.cf_cranetype)
GROUP BY
    cd.cf_firstname
```

Result will be:

```
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name     | cranetype                                                                             |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Alexy    | ROUGH TERRAIN CRANES, ALL TERRAIN CRANES                                              |
| Thomas   | ELEVATORS, ALL TERRAIN CRANES, YARD CRANES, ARICULATING BOOM CRANES                   |
| Thomaseg | ELEVATORS, ELEVATOR – HYDRAULIC, ALL TERRAIN CRANES                                   |
| Thomasxc | TRUCK CRANES: TELESCOPIC BOOM, MOBILE CRANES, CRAWLER CRANES, ARICULATING BOOM CRANES |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set
```

Comment: Great! Select the answer in order to close the topic.

Comment: ok..one more question ....how to check t conditions in this code SELECT
    cd.cf_firstname AS name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ct.cf_ctname SEPARATOR ', ') AS cranetype
FROM
    cranedetails cd,
    cranetype ct
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(ct.cf_ctid, cd.cf_cranetype)
GROUP BY
    cd.cf_firstname i want to check cd.cf_payment='top' AND cd.status='1'.

Comment: i want to check cd.cf_payment='top' AND cd.status='1'.

Comment: iam use this code  SELECT
    cd.cf_did AS id,
    cd.cf_companyname AS name,cd.cf_description AS descp, cd.cf_payment AS payment, cd.cf_status AS status,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ct.cf_ctname SEPARATOR ', ') AS cranetype
FROM
    cf_directory cd,
    cf_cranetype ct
WHERE  cd.cf_payment='top',cd.cf_status='1' AND
    FIND_IN_SET(ct.cf_ctid, cd.cf_cranetype)
GROUP By    cd.cf_did,cd.cf_companyname,cd.cf_description,cd.cf_payment,cd.cf_status ORDER BY cd.cf_did DESC LIMIT 4.  but not work

Answer (score -1):

Use sub queries to fetch this for reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html

Answer (score -1):

For me, it looks like you are storing a string value (or VARCHAR) of integer values (your cranetype ids) joined by comma.

If so, I would consider redesigning your database to have a table e.g.

- cranenames with cf_nid, cf_firstname
- cranetypes with cf_ctid cf_ctname
- cranedetails with cf_did, cf_nid, cf_ctid

In the cranedetails, make an entry for every cranetype associated with a cranename. The cf_nid and cf_ctid shoul be, of course, foreign key relations to the respective tables.

With your current design, you would have to explode the string value of your cf_cranetype to get an array of integers (or strings, looking like integers), and your second query had to look like this:
`"SELECT * FROM cf_cranetype WHERE cf_ctid IN '" . join($YOUR_ARRAY, ',') . "'"`

Comment: sir, this code "SELECT * FROM cf_cranetype WHERE cf_ctid IN '" . join($YOUR_ARRAY, ',') . "'" not work.

Comment: Did you rewrite your code to fetch the desired column and explode it into an array (in my example named $YOUR_ARRAY) ?